# Sending Core Data SQL in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: sql, ios9, mime, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've been having issues sending a core data SQL to an email address via `MFMailComposeViewController`. Below is my code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email@providor.com",nil]];

        NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Name.sqlite"];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        NSMutableData *mySQLData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
        [picker addAttachmentData:mySqlData mimeType:@"application/octet-stream" fileName:fileName];

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My issue is that the SQL being received has no data under the different titles in the entity. I downloaded the SQL from the phones documents directory, and there is data in there - so not sure what is happening between the email being sent, and received.

What's the issue? MIME type wrong? Data being sent corrupting? I'm so confused!

Comment: Have you checked the file path? Is it journaled (so there are 3 files to make up the store)?

Comment: Yeah there are 3 files that make up the store @Wain. Do I need them all when sending? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Yes, you do, you could zip them, but it's likely better to export the store content you want to JSON or similar

Comment: Could I use the NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption option, @Wain? or delete the wal and shm files?